# CakePHP logout issue

Tags: cakephp

this problem may look like little funny, I can't logout in my CakePHP site ! Here, login is alright, its working good, but logout is not working. This is the `AppController` code related to `login` and `logout` :

```
class AppController extends Controller{
     public $helpers=array('Session');
     public $components=array(
                           'Session',
                           'Auth'=>array(
                       'loginRedirect'=>array('controller'=>'controller1','action'=>'home'),
                       'logoutRedirect'=>array('controller'=>'controller2','action'=>'login'),
                       'authorize'=>array('Controller')
                           )
                       );
.
.
.
}
```

And this is the `logout()` function I am calling  from the `header` part of the site :

```
public function logout(){
      $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}
```

After `login`, the user is successfully redirected to `controller1/home`, but after logout, nothing happens. Even, after `login` the `header` part is also changed as I want, but after `logout`, it doesn't get the previous view. Like, I want some menus will be added after login, its working fine, but I want after logout, those extra menus will disappear, which is not happening here. And the redirection is not also happening. Please help me, I think its a very simple thing, I am missing someting.

Comment: Specify which version of CakePHP. 1.x? 2.x?

Comment: Almost looks like a duplicate.  Any specific errors or other hints? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969939/cakephp-logout-issues?rq=1

Comment: version 2.3.6-0 @starlocke

Comment: no, this is same as that problem. I am also facing the same problem, differnce is I am not doing anything after logging out, I just want to logout prefectly. And, I am not allowing not logged in users to "logout, I don't think its a good idea. what do you think ? @starlocke

Comment: is your `logout()`. action in your `controller2`. file? I was confused about what you meant when you put it in the "header" part of the file. Are you navigating to `controller2/logout`.

Comment: yes, logout() function is in controller 2. there is a "logout" link in the header part, src="controller2/logout". so, I want, when I click "logout", it'll redirect me to "controller2/login" function, that's it. @bowlerae

Comment: when you click logout, what URL are you sent to? Does the page refresh and you stay on controller2/logout or does it take you do a different URL?

Comment: the page refreshes and stay in the same page as it was. Suppose, if I am on "About" page, and click on "Logout", the page refreshes and remains there. But, I want the "login" page to appear after I logout.@bowlerae

Comment: You sure your code is correct? src="controller/logout" ? it should be href="controller2/logout" right?